# Is there a django-avatar app with REST API support?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, avatar

I am working on a django project that uses django avatar. But we also have other clients that are communicating with APIs. Does the django-avatar app have API endpoints or do I have to implement that myself?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement endpoint using the Django rest framework or you can write your own custom endpoint, but there is no API endpoint already available in the market.